# Calculating time difference between ID records - Should I use lag or diff?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to find the time gap between records for each `Consumer.Identity`. For example, each `Consumer.Identity` is independent. The difference between visits should only be calculated for each unique IDs.

Sample data:

```
tail(cs1[,c('Other', 'Consumer.Identity', 'timestamp')], 20)

      Other                    Consumer.Identity           timestamp
8830       672 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-05-29 19:15:00
8838       672 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-05-29 19:45:00
8788       674 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-05-30 13:26:00
12102      665 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-06 18:29:00
11749      663 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-09 08:15:00
11761      663 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-09 08:48:00
11696      663 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-09 14:12:00
11819      663 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-10 08:23:00
11912      663 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-10 16:13:00
13188      673 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-13 18:24:00
14235      667 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-16 15:24:00
14812      673 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-18 16:03:00
20523      650 ff98e12f-24fc-4072-adba-fd15c9481a84 2014-06-26 10:27:00
17856      657 ffa6dab4-361a-4ef0-8e23-53cd6084d01e 2015-01-07 22:59:00
18051      657 ffa6dab4-361a-4ef0-8e23-53cd6084d01e 2015-01-08 08:53:00
25860      657 ffab2368-3b2e-4ee3-9352-5c6520cf81b1 2014-07-30 15:27:00
17163      673 ffab2368-3b2e-4ee3-9352-5c6520cf81b1 2015-01-06 18:21:00
53407      670 ffc3af0b-f3ee-4ca7-a1db-4a9a1f1cf58d 2014-09-15 17:41:00
76334      667 fff9593f-3038-4986-9792-0960fdd87a1b 2014-08-13 17:01:00
41457      667 fff9593f-3038-4986-9792-0960fdd87a1b 2014-08-18 16:48:00
```

The following is my code. I want to create a separate field called `gap`. I'm also confused by whether to use `lag()` or `diff()`

```
cs1 %>%
  arrange(Consumer.Identity, timestamp) %>%
  group_by(Consumer.Identity) %>%
  mutate(gap = timestamp - lag(timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(Consumer.Identity) %>%
  mutate(gap = ifelse(row_number() == 1, NA, gap)) # first row of group is NA
```

Comment: What do you need the last two lines for? Doesn't it work without it too?

Comment: When you are using a non-standard package like `dplyr` it helps to tag your question as such and to make it clear in the example. I had no idea what was going on there at first. ;) I've put an edit in queue for this.

Comment: Either way, in certain cases they can differ, in your case I don't think it matters, rather that `lag` will return a vector of class `difftime`, Try `cs1 %>%
  arrange(Consumer.Identity, timestamp) %>%
  group_by(Consumer.Identity) %>%
  mutate(gap = timestamp - lag(timestamp),
         gap2 = c(NA, diff(timestamp)))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thank you. I was working off a previous example and you were correct - the last two lines aren't necessary. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, have an issue with the calculated field. It seems the program is confused whether or not to output in hours or seconds. If you look at row 3, 'gap' is calculated by hours and in row 13, the 'gap' is calculated by seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77092/discussion-between-herkyonparade-and-david-arenburg).